# BeautifulSoup: How to get only one part of <p> output?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to find the solution how to get only the price without text from the paragraph.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"}

p = requests.get(url = 'https://www.tia-mobiteli.hr/detaljan-prikaz.aspx?gid=11-appise_64wheu', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.content,'lxml')
price = soup.find('div', class_='widget widget-info widget-price').p.text
price2 = price.strip()
print(price2)
```

My output is:

```
Naša najniža cijena za gotovinsko/virmansko plaćanje: 3.649,00 kn
```

I want to get only:

```
3.649,00 kn
```

Or if it is possible:

```
3649.00
```

Comment: Hi! It looks like your question has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup, at all. You have a string with a number in it, and you want to isolate the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse` module that acts like reverse `format()`.
Usage:

```py
import parse
...
float(parse.parse('Naša najniža cijena za gotovinsko/virmansko plaćanje: {} kn',price2)[0].replace('.','').replace(',','.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The price is inside `<b>` tag:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"
}

p = requests.get(
    url="https://www.tia-mobiteli.hr/detaljan-prikaz.aspx?gid=11-appise_64wheu",
    headers=headers,
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.content, "lxml")
price = soup.find("div", class_="widget widget-info widget-price").b.text
price = float(price.split()[0].replace(".", "").replace(",", "."))
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
3649.0
```

Comment: Using `.replace(',', '.')` to interpret the number looks very hacky. There is [the `locale` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) specifically to deal with these kinds of things.